# Polymer web component bundling

Tags: node.js, polymer, web-component, vulcanize, mincer

I am using node/express to develop a web application. I am currently using connect-assets (https://github.com/adunkman/connect-assets) which internally uses mincer (https://github.com/nodeca/mincer), to manage css, js assets. Can it be extended to manage bundling polymer components using vulcanize? Any directions on how to get this working is highly appreciated.